# set the mouse pointer to be always on top (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, mouse, mouse-cursor

Is it possible to have the mouse pointer always on top, Even if the current program hides it? I am using windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of an "enforce mouse pointer" setting in Windows, so if a program is hiding the mouse, you'll probably have to go through the program's settings to change it.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that is not program specific.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with a specific program and not Windows 10. But you can try this:

1. Click the start menu and search for 'mouse'.
2. Open 'Mouse settings' or 'Mouse and touchpad settings'
3. You hopefully see a link saying 'Additional mouse options,' click it.

This will open up some mouse settings similar to what you see in this link that offers some things to try in a similar situation in Windows 7:
http://www.itninja.com/question/a-user-mouse-disappears-behind-windows-explorer-when-it-opens-up

To summarize, Click Pointer Options and enable and disable each of the options one at a time to see if any of those fix the issue for you.

Comment: I'm not having an issue, I was just wondering if it's possible.